# Cmake ctest generation

Tags: c, testing, cmake, ctest

i am using CMake together with ctest to generate software tests. 
As an example i have a binary `foo` which get's exactly three input arguments 
`p1` , `p2`, `p3`. The Parameters can range from 0-2. 
To check my binary `foo` with all possible combination of `p1`, `p2`, `p3`
i do the following in my CMakeList.txt

```
foreach(P1 0 1 2)
    foreach(P2 0 1 2)
        foreach(P3 0 1 2)
            add_test(foo-p1${P1}-p2${P2}-p3${P3} foo ${P1} ${P2} ${P3})
        endforeach(P3)
    endforeach(P2)
 endforeach(P3)
```

Is there a more "elegant" way to generate all these different tests?
Assume `foo` needs 10 Parameter `p1`,...,`p10` this would look horrible.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Didn't you miss the call to `foo` itself in the `add_test()` command line? Regarding your problem I don't know of any "parameter range" option in the `add_test()` command. So I don't think you can optimize this further within CMake.

Comment: yes you are right, i edited my post

Comment: One small optimization would be to use `RANGE` in `foreach()` like `foreach(P1 RANGE 0 2)`. Those things are used for iterating over test parameters [by CMake itself](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Tests/CMakeLists.txt#L1481).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use recursive functions for make test's generation "more elegant":

```
#  generate_tests n [...]
#
# Generate test for each combination of numbers in given range(s).
#
# Names of generated tests are ${test_name}-${i}[-...]
# Commands for generated test are ${test_command} ${i} [...]
#
# Variables `test_name` and `test_command` should be set before function's call.
function(generate_tests n)
    set(rest_args ${ARGN})
    list(LENGTH rest_args rest_args_len)
    foreach(i RANGE ${n})
        set(test_name "${test_name}-${i}")
        list(APPEND test_command ${i})
        if(rest_args_len EQUAL 0)
            add_test(${test_name} ${test_command}) # Final step
        else()
            generate_tests(${test_args}) # Recursive step
        endif()
    endforeach()
endfunction()

# Usage example 1
set(test_name foo)
set(test_command foo)
generate_tests(2 2 2) # Will generate same tests as in the question post

# Usage example 2
set(test_name bar)
set(test_command bar arg_first ) # `arg_first` will prepend generated command's parameters.
generate_tests(1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1) # 10 Ranges for generation. 3 * 2^9 = 1536 tests total.
```

Note, that in the second case (with 10 parameters for iterate) total number of tests is relatively large(1536). CMake configuration could be slow in that case.

Normally, such extensible testing is performed by special testing systems. CTest (for which tests are generated with command `add_test`) is a simplified testing system with a few features.

Comment: Do you know some of these called "special testing systems"?